# How to write a SQL script that deletes duplicate posts

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

I have a table with these columns:

```
id (pk, int identity), imei (varchar), name (varchar), lastconnected (datetime)
```

Some of the entries in this table have the same name and imei, but different id and different lastconnected date.

How can I effectively filter out all entries that have duplicates (with a SQL script), and then delete the one with the latest `lastconnected` date?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: And what happens when there are 3 (or more) rows with the same imei and name? You still want to delete just one of those rows and leave the other duplicates?

Comment: Using sql server

Comment: yes there are some that have 3 of the same row. Then i would like to delete 2 of 3. The one to not be deleted with the latest lastconnected date

Answer (score 1):

A simple `ROW_NUMBER` and `DELETE` should do the trick:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY imei, [name] ORDER BY lastconnected DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy and will solve your problem

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
 id int, 
 name varchar(10),
 imei varchar(10)
)
insert into @table select 1, 'a','a' 
insert into @table select 2, 'b','a' 
insert into @table select 3, 'c','a' 
insert into @table select 4, 'a','a' 
insert into @table select 5, 'c','a' 
insert into @table select 6, 'a','a' 
insert into @table select 7, 'c','a' 
insert into @table select 8, 'a','a' 

WHILE (exists (select '' from @table group by name , imei having count(*) > 1))  
BEGIN  
 delete from @table where id  in (
 select max(id)  from @table group by imei , name having count(*) > 1)   
End 

select * from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is to use `RANK()`.  This will delete all duplicates, not just the most recent, in cases where things are duplicated multiple times.

```
    delete a
    from (
        select id, imei, name, lastconnected, RANK() over(partition by imei, name order by lastconnected) as [rank] from #temp
    ) as a
    where a.rank>1
```

Answer (score -1):

It selects the maximum of the date for each combination of name and iemi and then deletes that particular row.

```
DELETE FROM yourtablee
WHERE (lastconnecteddate,name,imei) in 
                  (SELECT max(lastconnecteddate), name,imei
                     FROM yourtable
                 GROUP BY name,imei)
```